# SQL MAX(COUNT(*)) GROUP BY Alternatives?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've seen many topics about this and none of them is what I'm looking for.
Say we have this simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE A ( 
    id INT, 
    date DATETIME
);
```

I want to retrieve the MAX value after grouping.
So I do it as follow:

```
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE(id INT, count INT);
INSERT INTO @tmpTable SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM A GROUP BY id;
SELECT MAX(count) FROM @tmpTable;
```

Is there a better way of doing that?
I've seen a solution in a book that I'm reading that they do it as follows:

```
SELECT MAX(count) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM A GROUP BY id);
```

But this won't work :/ Could be that it works in newer T-SQL servers? Currently I'm using 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to add an alias name for your sub query. Try like:

```
SELECT MAX(sub.count1) FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count1 FROM A GROUP BY id) sub;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. Wow, really did not know that. Edited.

Comment: Yeah...I get it confused all the time between the different databases.  But, I agree with you that naming an alias `count` is generally not good :-)

Comment: Dang! @apomene nice catch! I had a feeling something is missing there :D I should probably contact the author of this book ^_^ Thanks again for the heads up!

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of `TOP`

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id,COUNT(*) AS MAXCOUNT
FROM A
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY MAXCOUNT DESC
```

If you wants the result with same max count use `TOP WITH TIES`

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Id,COUNT(*) AS MAXCOUNT
FROM A
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY MAXCOUNT DESC
```

Comment: thanks for sharing! I already tried this approach previously, the only problem with this approach, is when you have 2 records with the same count, you'll get only the first one. Therefore MAX will display both results even if they're the same.

Comment: @GiladReich I have updated the answer to retrieve the second one

Comment: Thank you! I never knew about `WITH TIES`! Seem like another simple and easy approach :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way of doing that?

We could try using analytic functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, COUNT(*) cnt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM A
    GROUP BY id
)

SELECT cnt
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This approach is to turn out a row number, ordered descending by the count, during your original aggregation query by `id`.  The `id` with the highest count then should be the first record (and this result should hold valid even if more than one `id` be tied for the highest count).

Regarding your original max query, see the answer by @apomene, and you are just missing an alias.

Comment: Interesting! I never used analytic functions, so it's good to know! Thanks for sharing! :)